# viewForTableColumn is not run (but objectValueForTableColumn is)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, nstableview

Whilst trying to create a view based table it keeps calling the **objectValueForTableColumn** function instead of the **viewForTableColumn**.

I have set the table view to "view based" in its settings. But still I cannot make it call the correct function. I've looked at the implementation of apples example (tableviewplayground) and at some points even copy pasted the IB and functions, still no progress.

The relevant code:

```
// Should run
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row 
{    
    return nil;
}

// Gets run
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return nil;
}
```

Two pictures, not sure how helpful they are but still. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CKCx.jpg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Does your `NSTableView` have its `delegate` set to the class that
  implements the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol?  (I ask because
  `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` is a delegate method whereas the
  `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is a data source method.)
- Are there any bindings that are set in IB?  (You mention that you
  copied the nib from an existing project.)  Check mainly for bindings
  to the `NSTableView` content binding and to the provided view's
  subviews (usually the text field.)
- Do you implement the `numberOfRowsInTableView:` method from the
  `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol and does it return a nonzero
  integer?

Finally, you might have a look at the *Table View Programming Guide* chapter on "Populating View-Based Table Views Programmatically" in the documentation.

Comment: Indeed it was supposed to be linked as a delegate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: First point was my problem. It's a little confusing these methods belong to different methods (protocol|datasource) Thanks!